# AngularJS: calling from one route to another, passing a parameter, $routeParams?

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to have one controller in AngularJS call another controller (well, actually another route), and pass in a parameter.  I'm trying to work out whether I'm better to:

1. Pass the parameter as a search string on the URL.  If so, then I can't work out how to do this, details below
2. Pass the parameter using a service.  This feels a bit like creating a global variable, which seems to me to have issues.  Again, if this is the right way, then I can't quite work out how it works.

To provide more detail, I'm building a sample app so I can learn how to bolt AngularJS onto an existing Rails app, using the restful API that Rails provide.  I'm writing a tutorial on that as I go so as to keep my thoughts straight, and potentially help others to do the same.  That tutorial is [here](http://technpol.wordpress.com/2013/09/03/angularjs-and-rails-tutorial-index/), the problem is currently on the 6th page of that tutorial.  The sample app is a sports league - it has clubs and teams.  A team lives within a club.

I want to be able to come to the teams list page directly, in which case I show all teams.  I also want to be able to come to the teams list view from a particular club, in which case I want to show just the teams within that club.  Outside of angular, this would imply to me that I come to /teams, which shows all teams, or I come to /teams?club_id=1, which shows teams for club_id=1.  I don't see this as a path thing - so I'd expect /teams/1 to be team 1, not teams for club 1, so I see it as a search parameter thing.

For the code I've tried, I've tried to edit my teams controller so that it uses $routeParam to extract the value.  When I do this and run the debugger, $routeParams.club_id is null (in fact, $routeParams overall is empty):

```
.controller( 'TeamCtrl', function TeamController( $scope, titleService, TeamRes, TeamInput, $dialog, $routeParams ) {
  titleService.setTitle( 'Team' );

  $scope.club_id = $routeParams.club_id;
```

I can see commentary saying that I need an ng-view in my HTML template for this to work, whereas my definition of the route is currently in the controller as follows:

```
.config(function config( $stateProvider ) {
  $stateProvider.state( 'team', {
    url: '/team',
    views: {
      "main": {
        controller: 'TeamCtrl',
        templateUrl: 'team/team.tpl.html'
      }
    }
  });
})
```

The html for this page is very simple, as it basically consists of a grid plus a couple of buttons:

```
<div>
  <h1>Team functions</h1>
</div>

<div class="body">
  <strong>Filter:</strong><input type="text" ng-model="filterOptions.filterText" />
  <div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions"></div>
  <button ng-click="newTeam()" class="btn btn-primary" >New Team</button>
</div>
```

Another option I have seen suggested is using a service/factory.  It seems possible to define a service within my teams controller, then have my clubs controller pass data into that service before calling the teams route.  To me that feels a little like declaring a global variable - it feels fragile in that if that variable doesn't get reset through some code defect or other unexpected problem, then next time I come to the page it will still have that club_id set.  Passing it on the route seems more deterministic - there seems less chance that it will hang around in global state somewhere.  Of course, the fact that I can't work out how to get a service to actually do this could also be part of the problem.

Before I go much further with working this out, I'm interested in whether one or the other of these options is the "better" way to handle the need.  I'm leaning towards the first (notwithstanding I haven't made it work yet), but the second seems to be more what people are recommending.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `$stateProvide`r which is part of `ui-router` an alternate to `$routeProvider.` What it means is that you would not get the routeParams since they are managed using `$routeProvider`.

ui-router has similar concept like `$stateParams`. Inject `$stateParams` into your controller and you would get the querystring parameters.

See documentation here https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing

Comment: OK, that makes sense, should have seen that.  I did wonder a bit at state provider v's route provider.  When I change to inject $stateParams, and console.log($stateParams) I still get an empty hash.  Is there more to it that I'm missing?  The url I'm hitting directly is: http://development-apps:3000/UI/index.html#/team?club_id=1.  I'd expected this to end up with $stateParams.club_id having a value of 1.

Comment: I think there is some issue with query parameters as defined here https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/84. You can try `$location.search()` to get the querystring parameters. Or define the parameters on the route.

Comment: Ah, I understand now.  I need to change my URL definition to tell it that I'm expecting a parameter, so url: '/team?club_id'.  I'll write a separate answer with the detail of the code, but mark this as correct because it pointed me to the right thing

Answer (score 2):

Summarising and providing a code snippet.

1. I was using $stateProvider not $routeProvider.  This came with ng-boilerplate, which I used as a base, but I hadn't realised that they were two entirely different routers, with $stateProvider having different functions.  This means that I need to use $stateParams not $routeParams
2. When using $stateProvider you cannot retrieve arbitrary search parameters on the URL, you need to specify which parameters your view is capable of responding to in order to access them

That then gives me these two code snippet to meet my needs, firstly in the javascript:

```
.controller( 'TeamCtrl', function TeamController( $scope, titleService, TeamRes, $dialog, $stateParams ) {
  titleService.setTitle( 'Team' );
  $scope.teams = TeamRes.query();

  console.log($stateParams);
  $scope.club_id = $stateParams.club_id;
```

And in the state provider:

```
.config(function config( $stateProvider ) {
  $stateProvider.state( 'team', {
    url: '/team?club_id',
    views: {
      "main": {
        controller: 'TeamCtrl',
        templateUrl: 'team/team.tpl.html'
      }
    }
  });
})
```

It makes much more sense now, thanks for the information.

Comment: Argggh thanks!I've been struggling to get the parameters transferred to the target state. I didn't realized you had to specify valid parameters in the route definition as well.